# Reload datatable by jquery but all data shown at page 1 (default 10 data every page)

Tags: jquery, ajax, pagination, datatables

I am using datatable for my code. I want to reload the table after data submit. 
But After data submitting all the records bind on page 1.
I am using codeigniter and jquery ajax

This my jquery code

```
$('.myTable').dataTable();

//process data
$(document).on('submit','#frm_add_main_menu',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#msg').removeClass('alert alert-danger');
    $('.loading').show();
    $('.overlay').show();
    var formObj = $(this);
    var formData= new FormData(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url+'admin/save_main_menu',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: formData,
        contentType : false,
        cache       : false,
        processData : false,
        success:function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            if (!data.success){
                if (data.errors){
                    $('.loading').hide();
                    $('.overlay').hide();
                    $('#modal_error_msg').modal('show');
                    $('#msg').html(data.errors).addClass('alert alert-danger');
                }
            }
            else{
                $('.loading').hide();
                $('.overlay').hide();
                $('#modal_add_menu').modal('hide');
                $('#modal_error_msg').modal('show');
                $('#msg').html(data.msg).addClass('alert alert-info');
                setTimeout(function(){$( ".myTable" ).load( "55 .myTable" );}, 100);
            }
        }//end function success
    });
});
```

After submit the data, my table is reloading but all data view at page 1 (default show data just 10).

Anyone help what's the problem?

thanks before.

Sorry My bad english.

Comment: You are not reloading dataTable, you just load something into the table DOM element.

Comment: can you give me the right code? I have follow tutorial at this https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload() but error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reload the table data from the source with [.DataTable().ajax.reload()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload())

```
$('.myTable').dataTable();

//process data
$(document).on('submit','#frm_add_main_menu',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#msg').removeClass('alert alert-danger');
    $('.loading').show();
    $('.overlay').show();
    var formObj = $(this);
    var formData= new FormData(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url+'admin/save_main_menu',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: formData,
        contentType : false,
        cache       : false,
        processData : false,
        success:function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            if (!data.success){
                if (data.errors){
                    $('.loading').hide();
                    $('.overlay').hide();
                    $('#modal_error_msg').modal('show');
                    $('#msg').html(data.errors).addClass('alert alert-danger');
                }
            }
            else{
                $('.loading').hide();
                $('.overlay').hide();
                $('#modal_add_menu').modal('hide');
                $('#modal_error_msg').modal('show');
                $('#msg').html(data.msg).addClass('alert alert-info');

                // reload the table
                $('.myTable').DataTable().ajax.reload();
            }
        }//end function success
    });
});
```

Comment: did You mean I put after `setTimeout(function(){$( ".myTable" ).load( "55 .myTable" );}, 100);` ?

Comment: @MardinoIsmail Replace `setTimeout(function(){$( ".myTable" ).load( "55 .myTable" );}, 100);` with `$('.myTable').DataTable().ajax.reload();`

Comment: i have tried this code before i implementation my code above. i have error message like this `DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1` and on my developer tools I get `TypeError: g is null`

Comment: Is your API sending json back correctly? Also see https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/38292/datatables-warning-table-id-table-id-invalid-json-response